# doxygen handling of Fortran type-bound procedures

Tags: fortran, doxygen

I am documenting some Fortran classes that include type-bound procedures (member functions) using doxygen (1.8.10). The documentation for the procedure is getting associated with the module containing the definition. I would prefer that the documentation get associated with the type it is bound to, for which I have not been able to achieve good results.

My typical method for defining a new type/class is to define a module `type_newtype` that includes only the definition of the new data type `newtype_t` along with type-bound procedures. Shown here, including a type-bound procedure for the new data type.

```fortran
module type_newtype
    implicit none


    !> Class documentation
    type, public :: newtype_t

        integer(ik)  :: val

    contains

        procedure :: set_val

    end type newtype_t


contains


    !> set val
    !!
    !! @param[in] self
    !! @param[in] i
    subroutine set_val(self,i)
        class(newtype_t),  intent(in)  :: self
        integer(ik),       intent(in)  :: i


        self%val = i

    end subroutine set_val


end module type_newtype
```

When doxygen processes the file, the entry for the type-bound procedure shows up under the module `type_newtype`, but not under the actual data type `newtype_t`.

I tried turning EXTRACT_ALL to ON. This puts an entry for the `set_val` type-bound procedure under `newtype_t` as well, but does not include any of the documentation. No brief, no variables in the interface.

My goal is to have the procedure documentation live inside its associated type. Not the module. Actually, both would be fine, but the entry only shows up complete under the module. I welcome any experience as well as recommendations on usage and style, as I am a relative newcomer to doxygen.

Comment: Doxygen does not support too many modern Fortran features.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting a [`@copydoc`](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc) at the type-bound procedure as described [here](https://dannyvanpoucke.be/oop-fortran-tut6-en/):

```
contains

    procedure :: set_val !< @copydoc type_newtype::set_val
```

Then the documentation should be copied. But the call-signature is missing in my case, which still seems to be a bug in doxygen. See [here](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Whither-Fortran-type-bound-procedure-documentation-td7710.html).